# How to handle Horizontal RecyclerView inside Vertical RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using a RecyclerView and inside this I added a Horizontal RecyclerView for showing images like a gallery.

I am inserting my RecyclerView rows one by one after user enter his details.

My main problem is I am selecting images through Camera or Gallery, and they are displaying well in horizontal RecyclerView.

However, when a user adds one more cell, then some previous images are coming in that cell. This is incorrect.

How can I resolve this problem?

### My main Activity:-

```
 private void addDoctorDetails() {

        try {
            personalInformatioDoctorCatogoryBeanArrayList.add(new PersonalInformatioDoctorCatogoryBean("Physician" + i, "MBBS" + i, "1985" + i,imagesBeanArrayList));
            personalInformationRecyclerDoctorCatogoryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            i++;
        } catch (Throwable throwable) {
            throwable.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

### PersonalInformationRecyclerDoctorCatogoryAdapter:-

```
private List<PersonalInformatioDoctorCatogoryBean> personalInformatioDoctorCatogoryBeanList;
    private Context context;

    public PersonalInformationRecyclerDoctorCatogoryAdapter(Context context, List<PersonalInformatioDoctorCatogoryBean> personalInformatioDoctorCatogoryBeanList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.personalInformatioDoctorCatogoryBeanList = personalInformatioDoctorCatogoryBeanList;
    }

    @Override
    public VHItem onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        try {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapter_personal_information_step2_list_items, parent, false);
            return new VHItem(v);
        } catch (Throwable throwable) {
            throwable.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(VHItem viewHolder, final int position) {

        try {

            viewHolder.speciality.setText(personalInformatioDoctorCatogoryBeanList.get(position).getSpeciality());
            viewHolder.qualification.setText(personalInformatioDoctorCatogoryBeanList.get(position).getQualification() + "(" + personalInformatioDoctorCatogoryBeanList.get(position).getYear() + ")");

            //Getting imagesBeanArrayList position images
            ArrayList<ImagesBean> imagesBeanArrayList = personalInformatioDoctorCatogoryBeanList.get(position).getImagesBeanList();

            //Set Horizental recyclerView  adapter
            HorizontalListAdapter horizontalListAdapter = new HorizontalListAdapter(context, imagesBeanArrayList);
            viewHolder.horizentalView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            viewHolder.horizentalView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
            viewHolder.horizentalView.setAdapter(horizontalListAdapter);
            viewHolder.horizentalView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

        } catch (Throwable throwable) {
            throwable.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return personalInformatioDoctorCatogoryBeanList.size();
    }

    class VHItem extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView speciality, qualification;
        private RecyclerView horizentalView;

        public VHItem(View view) {

            super(view);

            speciality = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.speciality_textview);
            qualification = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.qualification_textview);
            horizentalView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.horizontal_recycler);
        }
    }
```

### PersonalInformatioDoctorCatogoryBean:-

```
 private String speciality;
    private String qualification;
    private String year;
    private ArrayList<ImagesBean> imagesBeanList;

    public PersonalInformatioDoctorCatogoryBean(String speciality, String qualification, String year,ArrayList<ImagesBean> imagesBeanList) {
        this.speciality = speciality;
        this.qualification = qualification;
        this.year = year;
        this.imagesBeanList = imagesBeanList;
    }

    public String getSpeciality() {
        return speciality;
    }

    public void setSpeciality(String speciality) {
        this.speciality = speciality;
    }

    public String getQualification() {
        return qualification;
    }

    public void setQualification(String qualification) {
        this.qualification = qualification;
    }

    public String getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(String year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public ArrayList<ImagesBean> getImagesBeanList() {
        return imagesBeanList;
    }

    public void setImagesBeanList(ArrayList<ImagesBean> imagesBeanList) {
        this.imagesBeanList = imagesBeanList;
    }
```

### my cell:-

[image]

Comment: means user enter his details with adding his multiple cetrtificates

Comment: those certificates i am showing Inside Horizental recyclerView which is inside Vertical RecyclerView

Comment: when user enter his another details with another certificates previose certificates also coming in this cell that's what my problem i want to clear that previouse certificates and need to add new certificates in my arrayList

Comment: So, `getImagesBeanList().clear()`?

Comment: i hope u understand

Comment: u mean in OnBinderView after setting adapter do i have to clear this?

Comment: I don't know. You said " i want to clear that previous certificates and need to add new certificates in my arrayList". So do that. `clear()`, then `add()` the others.

Comment: u seen my Main Activity class ? there i am adding user details one by one with multiple images(means certificates) then details are adding in first cell, Now when user want to add new details with out images(means certificates) but according to my code previouse images are showing in second cell  also

Comment: i dont want to show them because second time user did not select images how can i handle this situation that's waht my problem

Comment: It's difficult for me to understand what you are trying to display without an image. Could you [edit] and show a screenshot, maybe?

Comment: wait i will show u,can u please wait?

Comment: hi please see this  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B05NQoG9RAmwaXZSMkd2MGRVNFk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: here when user enter his name qualification and with his images in first cell

Comment: when user adding another details with out selected images with diff name and qualification same first row images are diaplying second cell how that's what my problem

Comment: Can you please [edit] the question and upload the image using the editor upload button?

Comment: please see i sjust send small listview row

Comment: i hope u understand my question when i adding details each time i have to clear my images array list and adding right?

Answer (score 0):

In my observation, you are passing same reference of `imagesBeanArrayList` in each record insert. Try to pass fresh array when you add new one.

```
private void addDoctorDetails() {
    try {
        personalInformatioDoctorCatogoryBeanArrayList.add(
                new PersonalInformatioDoctorCatogoryBean(
                         "Physician" + i, "MBBS" + i, "1985" + i, 
                         new ArrayList<ImagesBean>()));

        personalInformationRecyclerDoctorCatogoryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        i++;
    } catch (Throwable throwable) {
        throwable.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think `i` needs to be a parameter here? And what is being thrown?

Comment: he has taken it globally i guess. So providing parameter is not required

Comment: just need to chnage ImagesArryList for each cell

Comment: @AbhiRam There is no need to spam multiple comments. Try to fit yout statements in a single textbox.

Comment: u understand my problem now?